# How to fix the inputshow message in normal GUl in java?

Tags: user-interface

For making the gui more secure I want to assess the output only writing on one and only word.

Comment: What is _inputshow message_? Is this for a Web application or a PC application of a smartphone application? Are you using a particular programming language? Have you taken the [tour]? (You get a bronze badge after you do.)

Comment: Input show message is a special functional message used in Java programming language. I wish to run that in esclipe JDK . I am taking Java programming language. I haven't got chance to do tour but will do for sure if I get chance. Thanks

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.